# auto-save not retrieving data when refresh in aem forms 6.2

Tags: forms, aem, autosave

**USECASE:**

I had a form and it needs to automatically save its data after a given interval of time and retrieve it when user refresh the page. For that, I use `autosave` functionality of AEM Forms.

**What I had done till now**

According to [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6-2/auto-save-an-adaptive-form.html) doc:

- I had created a form
- Enable autosave option in *form container*
- Specify `1` or `TRUE` in *Adaptive Form Event*
- Enable `Autosave for anonymous users`. For that, changed configuration in felix console, edit  `Forms Common Configuration Service` to `All Users`
- Save these settings.

The form is data and metadata is saved in `/content/forms/fp/admin/drafts` hierarchy.

drafts

-- data : it has data in xml format.

-- metadata : it has metadata associated with the node.

**Problem**

when I refresh the page, the from is not retrieving the saved value. Do I had missed something?

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you.